# Tkinter - is it possible to use two different grids in the same frame?

Tags: tkinter, grid

I wrote a simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def ChangeinItalian():
    MyLabel.configure(text="Ciao Ciao Ciao Ciao:")
def ChangeinEnglish():
    MyLabel.configure(text="Hi Hi Hi Hi:")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("550x350")

MyFrame=Frame(root, background="#ffffff", highlightbackground="#848a98", highlightthickness=1)
MyFrame.place(x=5, y=5, width=535, height=300)

MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=16)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=10)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(4, minsize=10)
MyFrame.grid_columnconfigure(6, minsize=16)
MyFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=16, pad=16)
MyFrame.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=16, pad=16)

ttk.Label(MyFrame, text="Introduction", background="#ffffff").grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="w")

Canvas(MyFrame, height=1, background="#a0a0a0", highlightthickness=0, highlightbackground="white").grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan=3, sticky="we")

MyLabel=ttk.Label(MyFrame, text="Hi Hi Hi Hi", background="#ffffff")
MyLabel.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w")

ttk.Entry(MyFrame, width=70).grid(row=3, column=3)
ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="...", width=5).grid(row=3, column=5, sticky="we")

ItalianButton=ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="Italiano", command=ChangeinItalian)
ItalianButton.place(x=16, y=150)
EnglishButton=ttk.Button(MyFrame, text="English", command=ChangeinEnglish)
EnglishButton.place(x=16, y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

the italian label disturbs the design that I have in my mind for my software. the second row (check my invisible grid) is composed by some items: "space" + "Introduction" + "space" + the Canvas. between the label and the Canvas I want always 5 pixels of blank space, but with the italian label placed in the row 4 and column 1, it's not possible. how can I solve this issue?

[image]

maybe I could solve my issue using two different grids but I think is not possible.. for more clarifications you can read also my comments with Bryan.

Comment: Please don't have two different examples. If the first example isn't valid for the question, please remove it.

Comment: I just did it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Grids aren't objects, but you can nest frames as deeply as you want and within each frame you can use `grid` or `pack` or `place` starting from scratch in each frame.

That being said, in your specific case if you don't want the "test test test" label to push the canvas over you can just have it span all of the columns.

```
test_label.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="w", columnspan=3)
```

I don't know if that's the right solution or not because it's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. It's a bit odd to have a 1 pixel high canvas, and the final answer depends on if you have any other widgets and what you want their behavior to be.

---

> keeping in mind that I want to use just the grid geometry manager

Personally, I recommend against the "I only want to use grid" mentality. `grid`, `pack`, and `place` all have strengths and weaknesses. You should use the right tool for the job, and `grid` isn't always the right tool. You can sometimes write one line of code using `pack` that does the work of three lines when using `grid`.

Comment: ciao Bryan! thanks for your reply and tips. your solution is not the right one, but it's not your fault, it's mine. probably I could not explain my issue as I wanted. I changed my example code. it's still simple, but it's better than before, because now you can see more objects in the frame. for the last two buttons, I used the place method and for the other ones I used the grid one, because, as you adviced me before, I realized that it's not really necessary use the grid method for all widgets, but what is the issue? the issue is my canvas..

Comment: I want to use it just to create a style, in my real software I placed this kind of canvas near to each title (in this example, the title is the label "Introduction"). the canvas must stay always 5 pixel after the label, but as you can see, if you change the language from english to italian, I can't reach this goal anymore because of the grid method, but I need the grid method, because I need to implement an automatic resize of my widgets when I change the language.

Comment: in my example this automatic resize process exists and it works, but not at all, because, as I already wrote, I want always 5 pixels between the "main" label and the canvas. how can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I refactored all of your code as an example of how to remove the dependencies that your widgets have on the master grid. The fact that I used `pack` has nothing to do with it. The dependencies were removed when widget combinations were put in their own frame.

```
import tkinter as tk, tkinter.ttk as ttk

#common formatting for our custom Frames
class PackedFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        #grid equivalent of filling the entire next available row
        self.pack(anchor='nw', side='top', fill='x')
        #inherit master background
        self.configure(bg=master['bg'])


#no dependency on master layout
class Introduction(PackedFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        PackedFrame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        ttk.Label(self, text="Introduction", background=self['bg']).pack(side='left')
        
        #here we use a Separator instead of a Canvas
        ttk.Style().configure('TSeparator', background="#a0a0a0")
        ttk.Separator(self, orient='vertical').pack(side='right', fill='x', expand=True, padx=8)


#no dependency on master layout
class LangFormField(PackedFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, command, lang='english', **kwargs):
        PackedFrame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        self.label = ttk.Label(self, background=self['bg'])
        self.label.pack(side='left', anchor='w')
        
        ttk.Entry(self).pack(side='left', anchor='w', fill='x', expand=True, padx=8)
        ttk.Button(self, text="...", width=5).pack(side='left', anchor='e')
        
        #call the appropriate language method
        if hasattr(self, lang) and callable(getattr(self, lang)):
            getattr(self, lang)()
        
    #TRANSLATIONS
    def italiano(self):
        self.label.configure(text='Ciao:')

    def english(self):
        self.label.configure(text='Hi:')


class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.configure(**kwargs)
        self.geometry("550x350")
        
        Introduction(self)
        
        ff = LangFormField(self, lambda:print('clicked'))

        ttk.Button(self, text="Italiano", command=ff.italiano).place(x=16, y=150)
        ttk.Button(self, text="English" , command=ff.english ).place(x=16, y=200)
        
        self.mainloop()


Root(background='#FFFFFF') if __name__ == "__main__" else None
```